# ScheduledExecutorService#scheduleAtFixedRate is not working

Tags: java, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

When I periodically perform a time-consuming task, the results do not meet my expectations.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);

    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
        System.out.println("start: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("end  : " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
/*
    start: 1539688734439
    end  : 1539688737442
    start: 1539688737443
    end  : 1539688740447
    start: 1539688740447
    end  : 1539688743452
    start: 1539688743452
    end  : 1539688746456
    start: 1539688746456
    end  : 1539688749461
    ...
 */
```

As shown above, 3 seconds between two `start` instead of 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly how it is designed, from the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-):

> If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then
>   subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently
>   execute.

Comment: What should I do to execute periodic scheduling without caring about execution time?

Comment: @HomJie This might help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42899546/how-to-schedule-a-task-at-fixed-rate-with-a-duration-longer-than-the-rate